# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError); not working

Tags: blackberry, cordova, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde

I am developing a blackberry application using html5 code.I need to find my current location and have to show that in Google map.I am running this in BB9780. It is running in simulator but it gives a wrong location(US location). But it is not running in device.

I suspect the below line is not executing.

> navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);

I am giving my code here.Please suggest me where I went wrong

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-  height,initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no">
  <script src="json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="cordova-1.7.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

  // Wait for Cordova to load

  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

 // Cordova is ready

 function onDeviceReady() {
    alert("onDeviceReady");
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
 }


 // onSuccess Geolocation

 function onSuccess(position) {
alert("onSuccess");
    var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
    element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '           + position.coords.latitude              + '<br />' +
                        'Longitude: '          + position.coords.longitude             + '<br />' +
                        'Altitude: '           + position.coords.altitude              + '<br />' +
                        'Accuracy: '           + position.coords.accuracy              + '<br />' +
                        'Altitude Accuracy: '  + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy      + '<br />' +
                        'Heading: '            + position.coords.heading               + '<br />' +
                        'Speed: '              + position.coords.speed                 + '<br />' +
                        'Timestamp: '          + new Date(position.timestamp)          + '<br />';
}

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object

function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
</script>
<title>Notification  Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
   <p id="geolocation">Finding geolocation...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its the line you suspect, what is the error message your getting?  Its probably the simulator as your code looks correct, though I'm only reading error.message and error.code.  This my version of onDeviceReady

```
 function onDeviceReady() {
    try {
        if(typeof(navigator.geolocation)!='undefined') gl = navigator.geolocation;
        else gl=google.gears.factory.create('beta.geolocation');
    }catch(e){}

    if (gl) {
        gl.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
        alert("Device Ready");
    } else {
        alert('not supported');
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

i get solution by restarting my device 
like i am not restarting my device from 1 month

So restart your device may you get solution

Answer (score 0):

please try to add `timeout:10000` to see the error log.. 
it is probably a timeout issue on your specific device
try:
`gl.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError,{timeout:10000});` instead

related issue i found on github:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation/issues/119#issuecomment-463897045

and here:
[phonegap geolocation always fail on timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859425/phonegap-geolocation-always-fail-on-timeout)