# phonegap geolocation always fail on timeout

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation, timeout, sencha-touch-2

I'm using sencha-touch 2.0 and phonegap 2.0.0 in my app to retrieve user's location.
When runing on my locahost, everything works just fine. However, when loading the .apk to my android 15 api's device (using eclipse and the adt plugin), every call to getCurrentLocation or watchPosition never returns...

here is my code:

```
geoOn: function(){
    var geoReady = navigator.geolocation || undefined;

    var onSuccess = function(position){
            Top5.app.alert('Geolocation success '+String(position.coords.latitude) + ' ' + String(position.coords.longitude),'Geolocation');
            var scope = Ext.getCmp('nestedList');
            scope.updateDistance(position.coords);
    };

    var onFailure = function(error){Top5.app.alert('Geolocation failed: '+String(error.code) + ' '+String(error.message),'Geolocation');};
    if (geoReady) {
        this.watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess ,onFailure,{timeout:6000,maximumAge: 3000,enableHighAccuracy: true});    
    }
    else{
        Ext.device.Geolocation.watchPosition({
                 frequency: 3000, // Update every 3 seconds
                 callback: function(position) {
                        this.updateDistance(position.coords);
                 },
                 failure: function() {
                   console.log('Geolocation Failure!');
                 },
                 scope:this
        });
    }
 },
 geoGet: function(){
     var geoReady = navigator.geolocation || undefined;
     if (geoReady) {

         var onSuccess = function(position){
             Top5.app.alert('Geolocation successful!!!');
             var scope = Ext.getCmp('nestedList');
             scope.updateDistance(position.coords);          
         };
         var onFailure = function(error){Top5.app.alert('Geolocation failed: '+String(error.code) + ' '+String(error.message),'Geolocation');};
         navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess,onFailure);
     }
     else{}
 },
 geoOff:function(){

     var geoReady = navigator.geolocation || undefined;
     if (geoReady) {
         navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchId);
         this.watchId = null;
     }
     else{
         Ext.device.Geolocation.clearWatch();
     }

 },
 updateDistance:function(coords){
     Top5.app.alert('updateDist','');
     var scope = Ext.getCmp('nestedList');
     var lat = coords.latitude,lon = coords.longitude;
     var store = scope.getStore();
     var i,record;
     for(i = 0; i < store.data.all.length; i++)
     {
         record = store.data.all[i];
         if(record.data.locationX){
            record.set('distance',Top5.app.getDistance(record.data.locationX,record.data.locationY,lat,lon).toFixed(3));
         }   
     }
}
```

**UPDATE:** So I walked out of my building and it worked... I need to go outside more often.
However, when I'm disabling the gps, I thought geoLocation will find my location using wifi connection - but it failes (I'm setting enableHighAccuracy: false). Why is that?

**UPDATE:**   Let me rephrase my question:
Does navigator.geolocation.watchPosition suppose to work both with GPS signal and wifi/g3 signals? How can I detect user location using internet connection only? currently, my code is working only with GPS, and when that option disabled or signal is blocked, geolocation isn't working.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I've managed to work it out.... However , I have no idea what actually solved it. All I've done is to change one of my model's structure. Can anyone see the connection to geolocation?

Comment: Same thing happened to me, when i moved to a window it started working

Comment: What did you do exactly?

Answer (score 32):

I know that maybe it is too late, but today i struggled with the same issue! The solution turned out to be very simple!

SOLUTION: Reboot the device.

That's all.

The problem is, that you never know when i user will get this kind of bug, so if your application relies heavily on geolocation i recommend you set a timeout in location options `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess, geoError, {timeout: 15000})` and alert user about the problem and possible solution.

P.S.
Keep in mind, that Geolocation can timeout for example if mobile data is turned off too, so reboot won't always fix it. On iPhone it uses cellular data to get your position, but on Android, it looks like the phone does not have access to cellular data unless 3G is turned on

Comment: Thanks Arthur!  I was having the same problem for weeks and couldn't work out why the Geolocation kept timing out.  And it was just a case of having to turn it off and on again!  It's now working fine.  But as you say, setting the timeout and showing a relevant alert to the user is very important, in case they come across the same problem too.

Comment: Keep in mind, that Geolocation can timeout for example if mobile data is turned off too. On iPhone it uses cellular data to get your position, but on Android, it looks like the phone does not have access to cellular data unless 3G is turned on.

Comment: I don't know how many hours I spent figuring our why it didn't work and simple REBOOT did it! TY

Comment: Reboot the device is a solution, but the question is "What is happening behind the doors ? any idea ?

Comment: maybe this entry helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21975117/android-gps-does-not-work-until-restart-on-new-phones

Comment: It seems that android does not have access to location if mobile data is turned off.

Comment: Initially I glanced over this answer and tried other things first. Strangely enough, it worked! Thank you

Comment: I had exact the same problem years after with ionic 2 and cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.4.1. After reboot everything works fine. But imagine, a lot of refactoring code comes before, hehe. ;-) thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 7):

It could sound stupid, but, did you activate the "Use Networks" option?

Go to Settings -> Location and security -> Use networks; and active it. I have passed all the afternoon watching the problem and it was that.

Comment: I had an issue where it would take for ever for success to return on a Galaxy S4, going to settings and toggling off location services and back on fixed my issues and success returned within a second or two.

Answer (score 7):

I restarted and restarted. I reset my phone to factory settings.

But nothing worked.

Until I set enablHighAccuracy from true to false.

And... Tada.... it works.

So :

```
var options;

options = {
    maximumAge: 30000,
    timeout: 5000,
    enableHighAccuracy: false
};
```

This used to work fine using PhoneGap 2.6.0. I needed to make this change since I'm now using Phonegap 3.3 - tested on a Wiko Cink+ phone.

Comment: set enablHighAccuracy false will not provide ACCURATE LOCATION, when you make it false, it gives your wifi, integerprovider's location which could be ended in another city or state in some case.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the Phonegap plugin geolocation plugin from your project. You won't need to make any changes to your JavaScript code as your device will fall back on the [standard HTML5 navigator.geolocation functionality](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html) which has the same method signature.

Assuming you're using PhoneGap 3.3, you just need to run:

```
cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.geolocation
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are running on an emulator, it may be because the device does not have a geolocation set.  Try setting the location by running the following, assuming your android emulator is on port 5554:

```
telnet localhost 5554
geo fix -0.001 51.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Restart your phone or Go to google map and check if gps is working over there.
I got it working.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to a working app after updating PhoneGap to version 3.6.3 from 3.5. After trying many other suggestions Arthur's answer worked. 15 seconds seemed too long to me so I used {timeout: 2000}. I'm guessing the new version is slower as my code worked fine before the update on the same devices. Thought I'd post as well as upvote him as everything I found in Google was about initial setup and mostly irrelevant to my situation.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 60000` and then **reboot your device**.

Answer (score 0):

From my trial and error analysis, its most likely: 
 1. The version of android you're using. On Lollipop and lower you may need to go to the phones location settings and enable high accuracy settings (using gps, wlan and mobile networks to get location). I had to do this on a kitkat phone.
 2. As others have mentioned, you can try changing the settings of getCurrentPosition by either enabling/disabling highaccuracy and adding a timeout.
3.If you're using ngCordova, make sure you installed it right and the location functions are actually being called. Use console to verify

Answer (score 0):

Try This Solution:

```
window.setInterval(checkPosition, 5000);

function checkPosition() {
 function onSuccess(position) {
    document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;
    document.getElementById('result2').innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;
 }

 // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
 //
 function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
        'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
 }
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
}
```