# Cordova getCurrentPosition() never returns

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, geolocation, cyanogenmod

My cordova version is 6.3.1, and I'm using cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.3.0.
Upon calling `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError)`, neither `onSuccess` or `onError` is ever fired. 
I have also tried using the cordova-plugin-locationservices plugin which utilizes Google Play Services for obtaining user location, but to the same result.
I am building for CyanogenMod 13 (Android 6), and am using microG for Google Play Services (Which works in every other app I have come across to date).
Code is below, thank you in advance.

```
    setInterval(function(){
       cordova.plugins.locationServices.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) { /* cordova-plugin-locationservices */
       //navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) { /* cordova-plugin-geolocation */
          alert('Location determined');
          console.log(pos);
        }, function(err) {
          alert('code: ' + err.code + '\n message: ' + err.message);
        });
    },3000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to give an option object with a timeout property, because if you don't, android device won't fire the error callback and so you won't see any error.

```
setInterval(function(){
       cordova.plugins.locationServices.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) { /* cordova-plugin-locationservices */
       //navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) { /* cordova-plugin-geolocation */
          alert('Location determined');
          console.log(pos);
        }, function(err) {
          alert('code: ' + err.code + '\n message: ' + err.message);
        }, { timeout: 5000} );
    },3000);
```

see the doc: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me in the right direction. I ended up receiving an error stating "timed out while receiving location", which pointed me to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21481475/2657558), and solved the problem. Cheers!